# How to run Asymptote with TeX Live?

Tags: texlive, asymptote

I'm using a clean installation of TeX Live on Windows 7, using TeXworks editor in pdfLaTeX mode. I've tried the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
 Text Text Text 
\begin{center} 
\begin{asy}
 size(5cm); draw(unitsquare); 
\end{asy} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And its produces a `.pdf`, but with no graphic. I understand that I may have to do a step with the `.asy` file, but what do I need to do with this `.asy` file?

For some reason I'm getting this when running the command suggested by Philipp (document is named `trial.tex`).
[image]

Just running the command `asy` seems to bring up asymptote ok though.

Comment: The usage is explained on page 82 of the manual (`texdoc asymptote`). Probably the `latexmk` method is the easiest one.

Comment: I've read that part of the guide, where do I type the "latexmk -pdf latexusage" command within TeXworks? Forgive my ignorance, I've only been using LaTeX for a day.

Comment: Also, am I right in putting this code in a file named latexmkrc in the same directory as the .tex file i'm working with?

`sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");`

If not, where does it go?

Comment: While using `latexmk` is indeed the easiest solution you should also be able to use `asymptote` without it. Assuming your main `tex` document is named `latexdoc` you have to compile the document once, then execute the following command via the command line: `asy latexdoc-*.asy` and then compile the document again with LaTeX.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting [this](http://i.imgur.com/j6a4F.jpg) when running that command (document is named trial.tex). Just running the command asy seems to bring up asymptote ok though.

Comment: @Andy The problem might be in the fact that the Windows shell doesn't do correct "globbing". Try `asy trial-1.asy`

Comment: @Andy egreg is probably onto the right solution here. You cannot count on `CMD.exe` to handle globbing operators, like `*`, in the same way that a `bash` shell does.

Comment: That has worked thank you :) If I wanted to automate it with latexmk, where do I enter the commands for that? Are they input in the .tex file or elsewhere?

Answer (score 7):

For me, this is as simple as adding a new tool to TeXworks
[image]

Running pdfLaTeX, the asymptote, the pdfLaTeX again seems to work fine (in the same way you would do pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, pdfLaTeX).

Alternatively, choosing LaTeXmk and building also produces the correct output.